# Kernel and Image of a linear transformation with dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I have the following here:

> Let $f:\mathcal{P_3 \rightarrow P_3}$ be the linear transformation defined by $f(p(x))=xp'(x)$. Find its kernel and image. What are the dimensions of the kernel and image?

So $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. So that means:

$x(p'(x))=0$

$x(3ax^2+2bx+c)=0$

But that means $x=0$ or $3ax^2+2bx+c=0$.

I'm not sure how to get the basis however.

For these vector to be LI, that would mean that $a,b,c$ all have to be $0$, so does that mean the kernel would just be $p(x)=d$ and the dimension would just be $1$?

I'm not sure about the image.

If I go ahead and transform the standard basis vectors, I get:

$f((1))=x(0)=0, f((x))=x(1)=x, f((x^2))=x(2x)=2x^2, f(x^3)=x(3x^2)=3x^3.$

However $0$ isn't LI so does that mean the image is $\{x,2x^2,3x^3\}$ and the dimension is 3?

Comment: yes you found the kernel right. It being one dimensional means the image is $3$ dimensional by Rank-Nullity Theorem. But the images of a basis in general need not be linearly independent. So you can't just say the images of your standard basis will become basis for the image. 

For this small dimensional example, it does turn out and easy to verify that $\{x,2x^2,3x^3\}$ is a basis for the image; however, in general it may not be as simple as just disregarding $0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(x)\in\ker f$, $xp'(x)$ is the null polynomial. Therefore, $p'(x)$ is the null polynomial, which means that $p(x)$ is a constant polynomial. And it is clear that if $p(x)$ is a constant polynomial, then $f\bigl(p(x)\bigr)=0$. So, $\ker f$ is the set of all constant polynomials, and therefore it is $1$-dimensional; it has a basis which consists of the constant polynomial $1$. So, by the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim\operatorname{Im}(f)=3$.

On the other hand, as you wrote, $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal P_3$, and therefore $\{f(1),f(x),f(x^2),f(x^3)\}$ spans $\operatorname{Im}(f)$. But $f(1)=0$. This, together with the fact that $\dim\operatorname{Im}(f)=3$, tells you that $\{f(x),f(x^2),f(x^3)\}$ is a basis of $\operatorname{Im}(f)$.  But $f(x)=x$, $f(x^2)=2x^2$ and $f(x^3)=3x^3$. So, $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is the space spanned by $\{x,2x^2,3x^3\}$ which is the space of those $p(x)\in\mathcal P_3$ whose constant term is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the definitions:

> If $T: V\to W$ is a linear transformation then the kernel of $T$ is defined as $$\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{\bf ker}(T)=\{v\in V: T(v)={\bf 0}_{W}\}}$$
> and the image of $T$ is defined as $$\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{\bf im}(T)=\{w\in W: \exists v\in V: T(v)=w\}}$$

Let the linear transformation
\begin{align*}
T: P_{3}(\mathbb{R})&\longrightarrow P_{3}(\mathbb{R})\\
p(x)&\longmapsto T(p(x))=xp'(x)
\end{align*}

By definition,
\begin{align*}
{\bf im}(T)&=\{c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}): \exists a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}): T(a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3})=c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}\}\\
&=\{ c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}):x(a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3})'=c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}\}\\
&=\{ c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}):x(b+2cx+3dx^{2})=c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}\}\\
&=\{c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}):0+bx+2cx^{2}+3dx^{3}=c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}\}\\
&=\left\{c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}): \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & |& c_{1}\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  | & c_{2}\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 &  | & c_{3}\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 &  | & c_{4}\\\end{bmatrix} \right\}\\
&=\left\{ c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}): c_{1}=0, c_{2},c_{3},c_{4}\in \mathbb{R}\right\}\\
&=\left\{0+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{4}x^{3}: c_{2},c_{3},c_{4}\in \mathbb{R}\right\}\\
&={\bf span}\left\{ x,x^{2},x^{3}\right\}
\end{align*}
Hence, $\dim {\bf im}(T)=3$.

By definition,

\begin{align*}
{\bf ker}(T)&=\{a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}): T(a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3})={\bf 0}_{P_{3}(\mathbb{R})}\}\\
&=\{ a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}): x(a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3})'=0+0x+0x^{2}+0x^{3}\}\\
&=\{a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}): x(b+2cx+3dx^{2})=0+0x+0x^{2}+0x^{3}\}\\
&=\{a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}): 0+bx+2cx^{2}+3dx^{3}=0+0x+0x^{2}+0x^{3}\}\\
&=\left\{a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}): \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & |& 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  | & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 &  | & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 &  | & 0\\\end{bmatrix} \right\}\\
&=\left\{ a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R}): a\in \mathbb{R}, b=c=d=0\right\}\\
&=\left\{a(1)+0x+0x^{2}+0x^{3}: a\in \mathbb{R}\right\}\\
&={\bf span}\left\{1\right\}
\end{align*}

Hence, $\dim {\bf ker}(T)=1$.

Notice the rank-nullity theorem says $$\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\dim {\bf ker}(T)+\dim {\bf im}(T)=\dim V}$$if $T:V\to W$ is a linear trasnformation with $V$ finite-dimensional. In our problem, we have,
$$1+3=4$$
since $\dim P_{n}(\mathbb{R})=n+1$ so it's all good dimensionally.